# Border width percentage

Tags: html, css, width, border, percentage

I am now using these codes to implement the borders on both sides of my page.

```
<style>
body {
border-left: 168px solid #F5E5D6;
border-right: 168px solid #F5E5D6;
}
</style>
```

It looks great with my screen resolution. Unfortunately, for the other resolution, the page will be deformed. So maybe know **how to change "168px" to 9% of the screen?**

Comment: For your purposes, it is probably easier just to use a separate wrapper element, in this case the root `<html>`: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9yF62/1/  Otherwise, see the Javascript solutions on the question linked by @CTravel.  Viewport units *should* be able to do this, but are very buggy in Chrome and [not supported at all in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):  http://fiddle.jshell.net/9yF62/ (try resizing the image)

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thank you so much, both of you, sir. I finally use this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9yF62/1 to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

With [viewport length units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), you can do this:

```
body {
    border-left: 9vw solid #F5E5D6;
    border-right: 9vw solid #F5E5D6;
}
```

`9vw` means "9% of the width of the viewport". However please note that these units are not supported by IE <= 8 or Firefox <= 19. [More info here on browser support.](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)